# Making an absolute element the width of its parent's parent

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-position

I have a drop down menu that is absolute positioned, it takes the width of its parent, set to 33% of its li.

Now when I shift the size down to mobile, I wish for the drop down menu to be 100% width of its parent's parent.

So basically on desktop:
I want the drop down to be the width of it's parent li.

On mobile:
I want the drop down to be the width of the entire nav.

I'm comfortable with the media queriers, I was just wondering how I could get the css to work.

```
<ul>
  <li class="n1">Nav 1</li>
  <li class="n2">Nav 2</li>
  <li class="n3">Nav 3
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>DropDown 1</li>
        <li>DropDown 2</li>
        <li>DropDown 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here's a fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W44XL/)

Ideally I would like a CSS only solution.

Comment: you cant id the client platform using css. u have to make 2 separate classes and attach the mobile/desktop one as needed using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the parents and only make the dropdown 100% width, you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/W44XL/6/

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    ul { position: relative; }
    li { position: static; }
    .dropdown { left: 0;
        right: 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following in  your `.dropdown` style

```
.dropdown{
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

& use following media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px) {
    ul{position:relative;}
    ul li{position:static;}
}
```

I'll advise you to give you base ul-li a class to avoid conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .dropdown, li{
        width: 100%;
    }    
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W44XL/5/)